# regex avoid .* consuming all the string with ? when extracting a submatch

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substring, wildcard

Suppose I have a string whose last characters are decimals.

I want to extract the substring before the decimal characters. I can do this:

```
lll = 'asdajsdjajdpaosdj1234'
result = re.search("(.*)[^\d]", lll).group()
```

which results in `asdajsdjajdpaosdj`.

However I was expecting that the following pattern in 'positive form' to be working anyway:

```
lll = 'asdajsdjajdpaosdj1234'
result = re.search("(.*?)\d+", lll).group()
```

This is returning the whole original string `asdajsdjajdpaosdj1234` but I wanted it to extract only `asdajsdjajdpaosdj`.

I was expecting `?` to limit `.*` from consuming all the characters but apparently it is not since the `result` will contain the whole string.

What is the correct way to use `?` and what is it doing in this case? How can I put the regular expression in the "positive" form i.e. subtracting only the first part of a matching patter?

Comment: If you're saying that the second pattern captures all of the string by using ".*?" and leaves nothing for \d+ to match, that's not what I'm seeing on my machine. The whole string is matched, but only the letters are captured.

Comment: You have group here. Get that group: `result.group(1)` will give what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Austin that's true: shall I delete the question being so obvious?